# Java GCs overhead: Does it matter if you have 10mb or 10gb of *referenced* objects?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, nio

The GC has to check and find out which objects can be collected. My question is whether having too many objects to be checked can cause a GC overhead or somehow the GC is smart enough to avoid having to iterate through all the objects to find out which one is not referenced anymore?

Comment: Have you run any experiments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does matter to the [mark-and-sweep collector](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html) how many objects you have. As to the *size* of those objects, that could matter too: a compacting collector would have more work to do if it needed to compact 10GB worth of stuff rather than 10MB of stuff.

Having said this, modern garbage collectors are extremely sophisticated (they operate on multiple heaps, do things in the background, can use multiple cores etc). They are also highly configurable. Furthermore, a typical JVM comes equipped with multiple garbage collectors.

It is therefore hard to give meaningful, precise answers to general questions like this.

Comment: For the bits which are concurrent. ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way this kind of thing is optimized is the concept of [Generational Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html).  (Look in Section 4). Apparently Java since 1.2 has had generational collection.

What this means is that often newer objects are likely to die more quickly, known as 'infant mortality'. These newer objects are put in a generation that is collected more aggressively. If an object has been around for an hour, it's likely to be around another 5 minutes and is put in a generation that's collected less frequently than the new objects. If an object survives for some time in the more frequently collected areas it'll be promoted to an less-frequently-collected generation.

This lets you not look at all active objects for each sweep.

Answer (score 1):

It has to iterate through all active objects to determine if an object is still used.  The G1 collector has 1 MB mega-objects (which knows all the references within the 1 MB) but the performance is much the same.

When you get into multi-GB solutions, one option is to use off heap memory which you manage yourself.  Or you can use a solution like [Zing](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/whatisit), which can handle tens of GB heap without significant pauses.

Comment: I could only suggest it will cost "real" money. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which GC algorithm is being used, in case-of mark-sweep, it does matter because mark sweep need to identify roots for GC using enumeration. [Here is link on how mark-sweep works](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/01/30/back-to-basics-mark-and-sweep-garbage-collection.aspx)