# Is there a GC in Java that does not introduce latency (stop-the-world) by perhaps running 100% concurrently?

Tags: java, optimization, garbage-collection, g1gc

Just curious. I heard something about the new G1GC addressing that latency problem. I can't / don't want to use RTSJ.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should look into Military-grade hard real-time Java by Aonix called PERC that uses deterministic garbage collection technology http://www.atego.com/products/aonix-perc/ more on Real-time Java http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any zero-pause garbage collectors.  But generally speaking a low-pause collector like CMS will do the job.

The problems with pauses and pause reduction are as follows:

- A zero-pause (or almost zero-pause) collection regime *significantly* increases overheads for normal program execution.  This is particularly true with multithreaded languages like Java.
- Schemes that use a dedicated thread or threads to do garbage collection can get swamped if the application generates too much garbage.
- Any GC scheme will give you poor performance if the application's memory usage patterns are too "lumpy" and/or you don't have enough physical and virtual memory.

Comment: There are pauseless GCs ([Azul's](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/faq#pauseless) for example which is meant as a server-side JVM) but definitely not in Oracle JVM itself.

Comment: Interesting read I found here with comments that discuss the issue on paused/pauseless GCs: http://blogs.forrester.com/john_r_rymer/10-06-21-why_im_worried_about_javas_future

Comment: @eee - I skimmed that.  But I don't understand what he's talking about with his 2Gb-per-JVM restriction.  64-bit HotSpot JVMs have been around for a long time ...

Comment: I skipped the 2GB parts and focused on the comments that mentioned pause/pauseless GCs. Anyway, the blog topic itself was written in 2010.

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in something like the [Zing JVM](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/whatisit).

Azul systems have put a lot of effort into low-latency JVM tuning. I believe there are also some interesting technical papers that explain how this is done.

Comment: Azul targets Zing JVM as a server-side JVM.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for the [CMS GC — concurrent mark sweep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/cms-6.html).

[image]

<sup>(source: [Memory Management in the JavaHotSpot™ Virtual Machine](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf), p.12)</sup>

---

December 2015 update: you might be interested in Azul's "pauseless" GC. See [Explanation of Azul's "pauseless" garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4491260/139010) for more.

Comment: Last time I checked, even CMS had stop-the-world latencies.

Comment: Hm. AFAIK, all the JVM GCs have this – I'm not sure it's even theoretically possible to write a GC that doesn't have _any_ stop-the-world. The CMS GC just has a _shorter_ stop-the-world.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the latest G1 Garbage collection in JDK 7.